# Android emulator camera - webcam orientation

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-camera, android-orientation

I am using my Mac webcam to simulate an Android front-camera in the emulator. Unfortunately the camera seems in landscape orientation - [screenshot](https://snag.gy/TZ8mlB.jpg), even though the emulator is in portrait one.

Note that the camera behaves properly on a real device (i.e. it has a portrait orientation).

My Emulator configuration: 
Nexus 5X, Android Nougat 7.1.1, API Level 25, Startup Orientation: portrait, front-camera: webcam0, back-camera: Emulated

How can I use the webcam with proper orientation?

Comment: What type of emulator are you using ?

Comment: Nexus 5X, Android Nougat 7.1.1 x86, Startup Orientation: portrait, API Level 25, Camera: front: webcam0, back: emulated

Comment: Did you try to add to your camera app camera.setDisplayOrientation(90); ?

Comment: nope. It behaves properly on a real device, though.

Comment: I'm using the Camera2 API which does not support setDisplayOrientation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ultimately I solved this by detecting if I'm running in an emulator:

```
public static boolean isEmulator() {
  return Build.FINGERPRINT.startsWith("generic")
    || Build.FINGERPRINT.startsWith("unknown")
    || Build.MODEL.contains("google_sdk")
    || Build.MODEL.contains("Emulator")
    || Build.MODEL.contains("Android SDK built for x86")
    || Build.MANUFACTURER.contains("Genymotion")
    || (Build.BRAND.startsWith("generic") && Build.DEVICE.startsWith("generic"))
    || "google_sdk".equals(Build.PRODUCT);
}
```

And then applying a transform to the preview texture:

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
Point displaySize = new Point();
display.getRealSize(size);
RectF viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, mCameraPreview.getWidth(), mCameraPreview.getHeight());
float centerX = viewRect.centerX();
float centerY = viewRect.centerY();
float scale = (float) mCameraPreview.getWidth() / (float) displaySize.x;
matrix.postScale(scale, scale, centerX, centerY);
matrix.postRotate(270, centerX, centerY);
mCameraPreview.setTransform(matrix);
```

Answer (score -1):

I enabled auto-rotation on emulator and then turned emulator to landscaped mode, and it worked.

Comment: This did not work in my case. With this trick I managed to rotate the camera 180 degrees off the intended orientation (upside-down), but not the correct orientation :(