# Camera app orientation issue

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-camera

I'm using the factory camera app on Android emulator (API 25, 26) to take captures of the emulated camera. It seems that when the orientation is portrait, the captures are rotated by 90 degrees.

Camera preview:

[image]

Captured image:

[image]

How come it's rotated by 90 degrees? The EXIF data seems to suggest the orientation is 0.

Any thought appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does an image captured using camera intent gets rotated on some devices on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14066038/why-does-an-image-captured-using-camera-intent-gets-rotated-on-some-devices-on-a)

Comment: This has been asked before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43605591/android-emulator-camera-webcam-orientation Here is the ultimate answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25310573/how-to-set-android-default-camera-app-for-portrait-orientation-only